# How to turn a sprite 90°

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a labyrinth kinda game in Unity and I want to make the character face to direction of the Arrow key on my keyboard, "as the player press right, the character should face right"

Here's what I got so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovimentoBola : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 10.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 100.0f;
public GameObject skull;
float posx, posy;
float rotx, roty, rotz; 



void Start()
{
    posx = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    posy = Time.deltaTime * speed;
    rotz = skull.transform.rotation.z;
}


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) //Seta pra cima
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, posy));            
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) //Seta pra baixo
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, -posy));
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) //Seta pra direita
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(posx, 0));
        rotz += 90;
    }              
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) //Seta pra esquerdas
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(-posx, 0));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What perspective (top-down or side view) are you using for your 2D game?  If you are using side view, you might have to use different sprites when the player is facing different directions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the sprite to reflect the direction the player is pressing?

The easiest way is to grab the *SpriteRender* and flip the X value. Something like this:

```
var sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
```

This will flip the sprite on the X axis and you won't have to mess with transforms and it will retain all animations. To go back, you just set it back to false.

Comment: Yeah, I think it worked better this way. I'll leave like this for now and if I have further problems with it I'll star another topic

Answer (score 2):

You can try to rotate the sprite using `transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);` or if you have let say 1 sprite for each direction, change the sprite using `gameObject.GetComponent<Sprite>().sprite = yourSprite`

Comment: Ok, it worked fine. What would I have to do in order for it to only turn if the sprite is not facing the right way and if facing the opposite direction, turn 180°?